Java/Kotlin exceptions - Can exceptions damage or slow down multi-threaded code, even when they're caught?
I'm using a 3rd party parser which listens to a TCP socket for strings, parses them and then callbacks with the results. Due to this types of operations, I guess it doesn't run on main thread.
The issue with this library is that it throws a lot of useless exceptions (e.g. when the parsed string is missing some optional field), one for each new string on the TCP socket.
I first didn't catch them and they didn't make the app crash, just logged the exception. Now I've added a try-catch block to handle all of them. My question is: can this still cause some performance issue, even if I catch all of them?
Note: my app is an Android app, but I guess it's not relevant here.
Thank you

I don't have any numbers, but yes, exceptions are pretty heavy. In order to throw we need to construct a stack trace, etc. Exceptions shouldn't be used for control flow or for non-erroneous application states. Your case is tricky, because you don't do this by yourself, this is the library. If you can't change or reconfigure it, then I guess you will get some performance hit. Still, the hit may be entirely neglectable, depending on how many exceptions are thrown.

Thank you, sad to read :) exceptions are quite a lot, it's a nmea parser for gnss sentences so there are like 30-40 messages per seconds, each of one throwing an exception. It'll be hard to do by myself or find another lib but I think I have no other choice.
